# Не работает код для телеграм бот на python

Tags: telegram-bot, telebot, python-telegram-bot

Задача бота — получить картинку и текст от человека и отправить в лс админу чата. У админа появляется это сообщение и 2 кнопки: "переслать" или "отклонить". Ели переслать, то бот пересылает это сообщение в чат. Переслать админу у меня получилось. Как от админа переслать в чат?

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda callback: True)
def callback_message(callback):
    if callback.data == 'opinion':
        bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, text='Отправь фото и текст одним сообщением')
        @bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
        def resend(message):
            markup2 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('переслать в группу', callback_data='adminResend')
            markup2.row(btn1)
            bot.copy_message(chat_id="...", from_chat_id=message.chat.id, message_id=message.id, reply_markup=markup2)
            markup2 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('назад', callback_data='delete1')
            markup2.row(btn1)
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Ваша запись отправлена на модерацию', reply_markup=markup2)
```

Пробовала внизу так дописать, но не работает.

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda callback: True)
def callback_message2(callback):
    if callback.data == 'adminResend':
        def admin_resend(callback, message):
            bot.forward_message(chat_id="@...", from_chat_id=callback.message.chat.id, message_id=message.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda callback: True)
def callback_message(callback):
    if callback.data == 'delete':
      bot.delete_message(callback.message.chat.id, callback.message.message_id)
    elif callback.data == 'adminResend':
        bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, text='Отправлено в чат')
        bot.copy_message(chat_id="@...", from_chat_id=callback.message.chat.id, message_id=callback.message.id)
```